# ASP.NET MVC How to Prevent re-POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Using MVC 4.

When an order is placed on our site the order is POSTed to:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ConfirmOrder(ABCModel model)
    {
        //Do Stuff
        return View("ConfirmedOrder", model);
    }
```

The user sees the Confirmed page.

If they press REFRESH in their browser, the page POSTs again.

Is there a way in MVC to prevent the POST again, perhaps in a redirect or some sort?

Comment: Make a send order method that gets posted to and if the order is successfully submitted redirect the user to the confirmed order page.  Short answer, separate the actions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of doing

`return View("ConfirmedOrder", model)`

separate your confirmation logic into a controller and do

`return RedirectToAction("ConfirmOrderActionName")`.

Here your `ConfirmOrderActionName` controller can retrieve the order information from the data store and sent it to its own view, or your `ConfirmedOrder` view.

**P.S.**

Note that `RedirectToAction()` helper method also returns a type of `ActionResult` (just like returning a `View()` does).

If you're interested see:

[MSDN: Controllers and Action Methods in ASP.NET MVC Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [MSDN: ActionResult Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 This is known as the Post/Redirect/Get pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 1):

You might want to redesign the logic a little bit. It is a command problem in Shopping Cart check out.

Here is how most Shopping Cart works -

```
Step 1. Cart (Create a Session here)

... Shipping, Payment and so on

Step 2: ConfirmOrder - Get (If no Session, redirect to Cart page.)
        ConfirmOrder - Post (If no Session, redirect to Cart page. If valid and 
                             check out successful, redirect to Complete page)

Step 3: Complete (Clear the Session)
```